# How to put add values on HTML forms in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm trying to put Javascript variable values into html forms in a Expression JS server, but I don't know how to approach the problem.

I just want to put values of x, y and res into the forms with id 'firstvalue', 'secondvalue', 'result', how i can do it?

I know it may sound simple but I'm really lost on it.

```
// No use of the template system
var express = require('express'),
    logger = require('morgan');
var app = express();
var x = 1;
var y = 2;
var res = x+y;

// Determining the contents of the middleware stack
app.use(logger('dev'));                         // Place an HTTP request recorder on the stack - each request will be logged in the console in 'dev' format
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // Place the built-in middleware 'express.static' - static content (files .css, .js, .jpg, etc.) will be provided from the 'public' directory

// Route definitions
app.get('/', function (req, res) { 

    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8"});
    res.write('<p1 id=firstnumber>x</h1>');
    res.write('<p1 id=secondnumber>y</p1>');
    res.write('<p1 id=result>res</h1>');

    res.end();
        // Send a response to the browser
})

// The application is to listen on port number 3000
app.listen(3000, function () {           
    console.log('The application is available on port 3000');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change your code like this?

```
res.write('<p1 id=firstnumber>' + x + '</h1>');
res.write('<p1 id=secondnumber>' + y + '</p1>');
res.write('<p1 id=result>' + res + '</h1>');
```

If you are doing some basic server side generated website may I suggest you to use something like this [express-handlebars-boilerplate](https://github.com/RoseRocket/express-handlebars-boilerplate)